# JavaScript Cookie Consent Notice Reappears Unless It Is Clicked Off On The Homepage

Tags: javascript, session, cookies

I'm coding a cookie consent notice that is working OK in terms of its functionality—when I'm on the homepage and click the 'OK' message to remove the banner it disappears and doesn't reshow.

However, if I click to remove the banner on any other page on the site it re-appears again when I visit another page (unless one of the subsequent pages is the homepage then it disappears for the duration of the cookie as it should when it is clicked).

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

**Update**

What I've noticed is if I click the notice away and then refresh the page, in the dev tools the cookie is showing the 'path' as the page name i.e `/contact` under Application > Cookies, but of course when I apply the cookie on the home page it applies the path as `/` which will then cover all of the site.

I guess I need a way of always setting the path to `/` whatever page the cookie is added on?

In the JavaScript below the code basically adds some CSS classes to fade out/remove the banner then a cookie is added to keep it off for 12 months (or until the cookie is removed obviously)

Many thanks for any help

Emily

```
// // COOKIES
var cookieButton = document.getElementsByClassName('cookie-button') [0],
cookieBanner = document.getElementsByClassName('cookie-banner') [0]

cookieButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    var cookieString = 'CookieConsent=true; expires=';
    var date = new Date();
    var expireDate = date.getTime() + (31536000000);
    date.setTime(expireDate);
    cookieString += date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cookieString;

    // fades out cookie banner
    cookieBanner.classList.add('cookie-fade')

})

// prevents cookie showing on next visit
if (document.cookie.split(';').filter(function(item) {
        return item.trim().indexOf('CookieConsent=') == 0
        }).length) {
    
        // prevents cookie notice showing on next visit
        cookieBanner.classList.add('hidden');
}
```

Comment: do you see any errors in the browser developer console?

Comment: @JaromandaX No, no errors are showing.

Comment: @JaromandaX What I've noticed though is if I click the notice away and then refresh the page, in the dev tools the cookie is showing the 'path' as the page name i.e `/contact` under Application > Cookies, but of course when I apply the cookie on the home page it applies the path as `/` which will then cover all of the site. I guess I need a way of always setting the path to `/` whatever page the cookie is added on?

Comment: add `; path=/` to your cookie then

Comment: @JaromandaX ah OK. I'm new to cookies so I didn't realise you could do that so easily. If you put that as answer I'll happily mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was to add `; path=/` to the `cookieString` variable.